# Extras not getting passed when using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP and CLEAR_TOP

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

```
doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(!imgUriList.isEmpty())
            {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), createAdActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgUriList);
                    startActivity(intent);


            }
        }
    });
```

> This is the code I have used in my second activity to send extras to the first activity.
>
> I want to keep the first activity as it is when coming back from the second activity. Therefore I have used _SINGLE_TOP,CLEAR_TOP FLAGS.
>
> Without the Flags it works well. But After using the extras extras become null. 
>   This is the Code I have used in my first activity.

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Toast.makeText(this,"IN RESUME ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        imageUris = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        if(getIntent().hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {
            if (!imageUris.isEmpty()) {
                createAdViewPagerAdapter viewpager = new createAdViewPagerAdapter(this,imageUris);
                photoViewer.setAdapter(viewpager);
            }
        }
    }
```

> Since the first activity also uses some extras sent from MainActivity I have overrides the onNewIntent()method as well.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```

Comment: You have override the `onNewIntent` but you did not check the argument `Intent intent`.   And put `getParcelableArrayListExtra` inside `if(getIntent().hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM))`.

Comment: OMG you just saved me a lot of time. Not  Checking the argument Intent was the issue.  By adding the line setIntent(intent); inside onNewIntent solved it right away.

Comment: @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
    }  THANK YOU SOO MUCH ADM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `getIntent()` you will get the old `Intent` you need to process the intent argument of `onNewIntent()`. You can use `setIntent(intent)` it will Change the intent returned by `getIntent()`. To make sure any further call to `getIntent()` will return the latest intent use `setIntent()`
.

```
 @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
   // Do further stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much..You are a lifesaver. Btw I have added the rest of the code on OnResume() method and it works fine. Does it have a impact? Do I have to move them inside the onNewIntent() method?

Comment: It will work fine i think. Or Create a method which handles the `getIntent()` and call it from both places. from `onCreate()` and `onNewIntent()`. `onResume()` will get called each time your Activity return from pause state . So Make a choice upon the requirement.